# Tensorflow 2.4 and Nvidia NVS 310

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I trained some models with tensorflow 2.4 and I'm looking for some help from gpu and I install:

1. CUDA 11.0
2. 2. cuDNN 8.0.4
3. 3. Tensorflow 2.4

#### My gpu:

Nvidia NVS 310

But still when I import tensorflow library it give me callbacks with some problems, when I use this:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

I got nothing.
I looked a lot and thought that my gpu (NVS 310) is not support by tensorflow 2.4. Can someone if I'm right or not?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a chip from 2012. (Fermi architecture). You'd need a Kepler or better card; Fermi hasn't been supported since at least driver version 384.111